# how to access config.groovy values in src/java file?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am not able to access config.groovy properties in java file
I wrote it like this:

```
ConfigObject holder = ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() ;
private String configEndPoint = holder.getProperty( "mks.elasticCache.endPoint" ).toString() ;
```

But values coming as null.

Comment: What version of Grails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the flatConfig, not the config.  In any matter assuming you are on Grails 2+, ConfigurationHolder is deprecated.

You should be able to replace the above with:

```
import grails.util.Holders ;

...

String endpoint = Holders.getFlatConfig()
                         .get( "mks.elasticCache.endPoint" )
```

Comment: Yea, didn't see the java class and the famous semicolon used in your import. :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: should be `grails.util.Holders`. Notice `utils` vs. `util`

Answer (score 1):

Above version Grails 2.2 you can get through `grails.util.Holders` class
like  `Holders.getFlatConfig().get("your.property.name");`

Answer (score 0):

```
Holders.getConfig().get("mks").getAt("elasticCache").getAt("endPoint")
```

or

```
Holders.getFlatConfig().get("mks.elasticCache.endPoint");
```